# How to translate a "for loop in R" to Julia

Tags: julia

How can I translate the following code of R to Julia? I am new in Julia.

I know Julia has different ways to replace for loop.

```
max_trial <- max(dataframe[,1])


max_c1 <- NA
  for(c in 1:max_trial){
    c1 <- which(dataframe[,1]==c)
     max_measure <- max(dataframe[c1,2])
     max_c1[c] <- max_measure
  }
```

As suggested I applied the following code translate

```
max_c1= []
for c in 1:max_trial
    c1 = findall(dataframe[:,1] .== c)
    max_c1[c] = maximum(dataframe[c1,2])
end
```

But I received the following error

> ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{Any,1} at index [1]

Also the values received from this translation “ maximum(dataframe[c1,2])” is still different than The R code. It seems for this part of error some adjustment of the syntax needs improvement.

Comment: Instead of `max_trial = []`, rather have `max_trail = Array{Any}(undef, max_trial)`. Julia is less forgiving in terms of arrays than R.

Comment: You have edited your other question but the only people who are likely to see it are those with  high rep who know it is there. You should undelete it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the corresponding Julia code would look like

```
for c in 1:max_trial
    c1 = findall(dataframe[:,1] .== c)
    max_c1[c] = maximum(dataframe[c1,2])
end
```

although I think you did not give enough information to completely answer your question, so I'm not really sure. Maybe adding the data you used and the output you are looking for in your question would help?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Benoit. This code is part of very long function to detect fraud in clinical trials based on Monte Carlo Simulation and it work great in R but very slow so I am translating it to Julia.                                                              # Name of trials 
  naming = unique(dataframe[!,:9])
  dataframe = dataframe[!,:1:8]
  # Number of trials 
  max_trial = maximum(dataframe[!,:1])
  # Number of variables on each trial 
  max_c1 = []
  for c in 1:max_trial
      c1 = findall(dataframe[:,1] .== c)
      max_c1[c] = maximum(dataframe[c1,2])
  end

Comment: The code is now give this error. ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{Any,1} at index [1]

Comment: It's hard to read the code in comments... Could you edit your original post instead?

Comment: I edited the post please help. The line of maximum also does not translate the line of max in R exactly as the value produced by the R line is 32 while Julia give 18.

Comment: I get you cannot copy your entire code and data here, but could you make a minimal example, with dummy data, and with the output you want, so that one can just copy-paste and run? This would help others help you!

Comment: I sent the data and code to your email for your kind help.